# Translation of Wordpress menu items when setting the locale programmatically

Tags: wordpress

I have English and Deutch languages, WordPress 6.0. I programmatically set the language using **switch_to_locale('de_DE');** (depends on URL).

```
add_action( 'plugin_loaded', 'set_lang');
function set_lang() {
    switch_to_locale('de_DE');
}
```

Everything translates except menu items.

Menu items are translated if I set **?lang=de** in the URL or execute **$REQUEST['lang'] = 'de';** in hook **plugins_loaded**

This solution works but does not look correct. Tell me, please, how to programmatically set the language more correctly so that the menu is also translated.

I use Max Mega Menu and WP Multilang for Translation.
I tried to use another template and menu plugin but it doesn't change language.

I tried to use **add_filter('locale', .. )** but it doesn't help.

I tried to use **switch_to_locale()** in another hooks but it doesn`t help.

Thank you very much for your attention, I will be glad to solve my problem! Hope this helps more than just me.